# How to make a ctypes.Array?

Tags: python, numpy, ctypes

I'm trying to get this `ctypes.Array` to work and keep getting a `TypeError: a float is required`.

```
import ctypes
import numpy as np

m = np.zeros((n_inst,n_inst), dtype=np.float64)
ctypes.Array(ctypes.c_double, len(m.data))(*m.data)
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Highly recommend the [NumPy ctypes](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.ctypes.html) library. I am assuming that you would like a pointer to pass into a C library. The following will expose the C function `myfunc(double* data)`:

```
mylib = np.ctypeslib.load_library("mylib", ".")

mylib.myfunc.argtypes = (np.ctypeslib.ndpointer(), )
```

Which can then be called as:

```
mylib.myfunc(np.zeros((5, 5)))
```

Comment: I just get an error OSError: no file with expected extension